# Download latest artifacts from Cirrus CI

Tags: continuous-integration, cirrus-ci

I'm trying to download the latest artifacts of a Cirrus CI build on a Github repo, and according to the [docs](https://cirrus-ci.org/guide/writing-tasks/#latest-build-artifacts), it is
`https://api.cirrus-ci.com/v1/artifact/github/<USER OR ORGANIZATION>/<REPOSITORY>/<TASK NAME OR ALIAS>/<ARTIFACTS_NAME>/<PATH>`.

Applying it to https://github.com/SDP-Rock-Paper-Scissors/RockPaperScissors, I get https://api.cirrus-ci.com/v1/artifact/github/SDP-Rock-Paper-Scissors/RockPaperScissors/check_android/jacoco_coverage/app/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/html/index.html but that doesn't seem to work, am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **Alias** to your task and download it by alias.

```
wheel_macos_arm_task:
  only_if: $CIRRUS_BRANCH == 'master'
  name: macosx • Apple Silicon
  alias: wheel_macos_arm
  macos_instance:
    image: ghcr.io/cirruslabs/macos-monterey-xcode

  env:
    PATH: /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin:$PATH

  install_pre_requirements_script:
    - brew install python@3.10
    - ln -s python3 /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.10/bin/python
  install_cibuildwheel_script:
    - python -m pip install cibuildwheel==2.11.4
  run_cibuildwheel_script:
    - cibuildwheel
  wheels_artifacts:
    path: "wheelhouse/*"
```

https://api.cirrus-ci.com/v1/artifact/github/GITHUB_USERNAME/PROJECT_NAME/wheel_macos_arm/wheels.zip